# Draggable overlay that can go offscreen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

- I have created an overlay menu that is a rectangle.
- It displays on top of everything else while active. All other apps, the home screen, etc.
- If you click anywhere outside of this rectangle your click hits
  whatever is visible.
- If you click the red part it allows you to drag the menu around the
  screen. Clicking the green part performs some function.

[image: example1] [image: example2]

I have created this rectangle from inflating layout xml. The rectangle itself is a relativeLayout and the green and red parts are both imageView children.

Since I'm unable to move the relativeView off screen and since the background needs to be clickable my only solution was to calculate margins and apply them to the relative view to imitate the desired effect.

However, the code to calculate these margins is almost 50 lines and fairly complex and hard to understand at a glance if someone else needs to refactor. I can post the code but I don't believe it's relevant to the actual problem's context.

**Is there a much simpler way to do this that I'm missing? Is my approach wrong?**

Comment: It may be too late for this. But why do you need a floating view that can make users mad? Can't you dock it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simple project may help you [Android Floating Widget](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/)

Comment: I'm afraid not. That example doesn't ever clip off screen.